# How to fetch a variable value outside Foreach loop in XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
  <Quote>    
        <xsl:variable name="ProductPos"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="SubtotalPos"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="Configuration"> 

            <ConfigItem>
                <xsl:variable name="ConfigurationPos" select="position()*10"/> 
                 <xsl:for-each select="ProductLineItem">
                    <ProductLineItem>
                        <xsl:variable name="ProductPos" select="$ConfigurationPos+(position()*10)"/>
                        <ProductPostionNumber><xsl:value-of select = "$ProductPos" /></ProductPostionNumber>
                        </ProductLineItem>   
                    </xsl:for-each>
                <Subtotal><xsl:value-of select="$ProductPos"/></Subtotal>
            </ConfigItem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Quote>
```

in the above Example i need subtotal tag value to be filled with $prodPos+10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a small change to your code. You can write into a variable if you don't close the tags immediately. This way you preserve your structure, but you can access it with your code.

```
<xsl:variable name="content">
    <Configuration>
        <ProductLineItem></ProductLineItem>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration>
        <ProductLineItem></ProductLineItem>
        <ProductLineItem></ProductLineItem>
    </Configuration>
</xsl:variable>
<Quote>    
    <xsl:variable name="GeneratedStructure">
        <xsl:for-each select="$content/Configuration"> 
            <ConfigItem>
                <xsl:variable name="ConfigurationPos" select="position()*10"/> 
                <xsl:variable name="ProductLineItem">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ProductLineItem">
                           <ProductLineItem>
                               <xsl:variable name="ProductPos" select="$ConfigurationPos+(position()*10)"/>
                               <ProductPostionNumber><xsl:value-of select = "$ProductPos" /></ProductPostionNumber>
                           </ProductLineItem>   
                       </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$ProductLineItem"/>
                <Subtotal><xsl:value-of select="sum($ProductLineItem/ProductLineItem/ProductPostionNumber)"/></Subtotal>
            </ConfigItem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$GeneratedStructure"/> <!-- This will output the content of the variable -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$GeneratedStructure/ConfigItem/Subtotal">
        <xsl:element name="Subtotal{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(.) + 10"/><!-- You did not specify if it should simply add 10 or add how often the for each loop repeats. Fix this for your needs. -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Quote>
```

Current output:

```
<ConfigItem>
    <ProductLineItem>
        <ProductPostionNumber>20</ProductPostionNumber>
    </ProductLineItem>
    <Subtotal>20</Subtotal>
</ConfigItem>
<ConfigItem>
    <ProductLineItem>
        <ProductPostionNumber>30</ProductPostionNumber>
    </ProductLineItem>
    <ProductLineItem>
        <ProductPostionNumber>40</ProductPostionNumber>
    </ProductLineItem>
    <Subtotal>70</Subtotal>
</ConfigItem>
<Subtotal1>30</Subtotal1>
<Subtotal2>80</Subtotal2>
```

Please consider checking your spelling, because it is hard to assume what variable you mean, if you call it by other names.

EDIT: I did edit it to your needs. Although it is not clear what you exactly want to do. If you show me some input and expected output I could fix this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the fix , but it doesn't satisfy my need , the output is like <subtotapos>203040506070809010011012013014015016017018019020021022023024025026030</subtotapos> , Actually what i need is if the foreach loop loops for 10 times then the new value should be (10*10) +10, and i need this result outside the loop , i am sorry i did not placed my requirement correctly

Comment: Actually the result is not adding even if it add, it solves my problem